pandoc installation on gitlab-ci.yaml for converting text to pdf files (Automation)
I am using Gitlab as CI/CD tool. Here I want to get all the .java files from various repositories and find the .java files & convert to pdf file. I have written a pipeline stage to convert to pdf like this:
convert_to_pdf:
  stage: convert
  image:
    name: pandoc/latex:edge-alpine
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    # Ensure the output directory exists
    - mkdir -p combined_output

    # Find the project directory in the current directory
    - echo "Searching for the directory..."
    - SB_DIR=$(find . -type d -name "sale")
    - if [ -z "$SB_DIR" ]; then echo "sale directory not found!"; exit 1; fi

    # Search for all .java files recursively inside sales_invoice
    - echo "Listing all .java files within $SB_DIR recursively..."
    - JAVA_FILES=$(find $SB_DIR -type f -name "*.java")
    - if [ -z "$JAVA_FILES" ]; then echo "No .java files found!"; exit 1; fi
    - echo "Found .java files:"
    - echo "$JAVA_FILES"

    # Combine all found .java files into a single file
    - echo "Combining all .java files into a single file..."
    - cat $JAVA_FILES > combined_output/all_code.java
    - echo "Contents of combined file:"
    # - cat combined_output/all_code.java

    # Convert the combined file to PDF
    - echo "Converting combined file to PDF..."
    - pandoc -f markdown -o combined_output/output.pdf combined_output/all_code.java --pdf-engine=pdflatex
    - echo "PDF conversion completed."

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - combined_output/output.pdf

First I used pdflatex as my pdf-engine. Later I got an error like:
error producing pdf. ! undefined control sequence. l.8220 from \n.

I searched the solution for this & I got this link: Pandoc: Error producing PDF. ! Undefined control sequence.
After that I changed my stage using pdfgroof but now I was getting error like:
$ apt-get install pandoc groff ghostscript -y
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package groff is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'groff' has no installation candidate
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I have tried with writing the dockerfile to install pandoc & miktex & texlive and its dependencies, but this also failed with error. I have tried with all other pdf engines on the gitlab-ci.yaml file.
Is there any solution or workaround for this?

I found the solution for the above problem.
pandoc expects markdown or a specific format, and directly converting .java files without proper formatting can lead to issues.
Root Cause
The issue is that .java files are plain text files containing code, which pandoc is not inherently designed to handle as-is, especially for PDF conversion using LaTeX. pandoc tries to interpret the Java code as markdown or LaTeX, leading to undefined control sequences or other LaTeX errors because the syntax of Java code is not compatible with LaTeX's expectations.
Solution
To convert .java files to a PDF using pandoc, you need to properly format the contents to be compatible with LaTeX or markdown.
I updated my pipeline stage as,
convert_to_pdf:
  stage: convert
  image:
    name: pandoc/latex:edge-alpine
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir -p combined_output

    # Find the project directory named "saleorder"
    - SB_DIR=$(find . -type d -name "saleorder")
    - if [ -z "$SB_DIR" ]; then echo "saleorder directory not found!"; exit 1; fi

    # Find all .java files in the directory
    - JAVA_FILES=$(find $SB_DIR -type f -name "*.java")
    - if [ -z "$JAVA_FILES" ]; then echo "No .java files found!"; exit 1; fi

    # Create a temporary markdown file for pandoc
    - echo "Creating a temporary markdown file..."
    - TEMP_MD="combined_output/temp.md"
    - touch $TEMP_MD

    # Wrap .java files in markdown code blocks
    - for FILE in $JAVA_FILES; do
        echo "Processing $FILE...";
        echo "\`\`\`java" >> $TEMP_MD;
        cat $FILE >> $TEMP_MD;
        echo "\`\`\`" >> $TEMP_MD;
      done

    # Convert the markdown file to PDF
    - echo "Converting the markdown file to PDF..."
    - pandoc $TEMP_MD -o combined_output/output.pdf --pdf-engine=pdflatex

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - combined_output/output.pdf

